# How to compare commits like TFVC changesets?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

We've made the jump from TFVC to Git within TFS, and it's working really well - however the only thing I can't quite figure out is how you can see ALL differences between two specific commits?

i.e.

> (entire repo as of commit X - DIFFED AGAINST - entire repo as
>   of commit Y)

In TFVC land, you could simply compare an entire changeset against a previous changeset, in a nice list with one set of files on the left, one on the right, different files marked in red - and you can click into an individual file to view the diff.

This was awesome to get a feel for how an application worked at one point in time compared to now.

The thing is, I can't seem to find this functionality baked in anywhere, or in any third-party (free) tools! I can see the code that changed per commit but this is no way near an effective view than what we are used to as a department, and some people are bemoaning the switch (despite all the positives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out SourceTree (Atlassian) offers this functionality, you can click one commit and right-click another and it shows the differences between those two :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to do a diff between two commits:

```
git diff <sha_commit_1>..<sha_commit_2>
```

You can also use difftool to launch the default difftool:

```
git difftool <sha_commit_1>..<sha_commit_2>
```

This will open the default difftool.

Here's the documentation for the command: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool
You can configure the difftool in the git options. Look in the reference for this at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config for anything starting with `diff`

Comment: But is there not a GUI based solution for this, that looks similar to TFVC?